# Not able to edit attributes using AJAX on Rails 3

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a view called hot.html.erb that lists items called "issues". I want a user to be able to simply change an option value and instantly submit the change using AJAX to update the database for things like "status".

What's happening is that when the option is selected, the database is updated, but I am redirected to the show.html.erb view. I would like to stay on the hot.html.erb view. I have a feeling I am not understanding the format.js entry and what needs to be done. Any help would be appreciated.

I am using jquery, query_ujs, rails.js.

I have implemented the following update.html.erb in my IssuesController:

```
def update
    @issue = Issue.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @issue.update_attributes(params[:issue])
        format.html { redirect_to(@issue, :notice => 'Issue was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
        format.js   { render :nothing => true }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @issue.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is my index page (hot.html.erb) with a form for the select fields where I want the user to be able to change 'status' and 'priority':

```
<% @issues.each do |issue| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= issue.description %></td>
    <td><%= issue.notes %></td>
    <%= form_for(issue, :remote => true) do |f| %>
    <td><%= f.select :status, [["Emerging", "emerging"], ["Investigating", "investigating"], ["Scheduled for Update", "Scheduled for Update"]], {}, :onchange => 'this.form.submit();' %>
    </td>
    <td><%= f.select :priority, [["Thermonuclear", "nuclear"],["Hot", "hot"], ["Warm", "warm"], ["Cool", "cool"]], {}, :onchange => 'this.form.submit();' %>
    </td>
    <% end %>
    <td><%= issue.case %></td>
    <td><%= issue.location %></td>
    <td><%= issue.customer.account_name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', issue %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_issue_path(issue) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', issue, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>   </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK. I found the answer I needed to make this work. I used this code for each of my select tags:

```
<td><%= f.select :status, [["Emerging", "emerging"], ["Investigating", "investigating"], ["Scheduled for Update", "Scheduled for Update"]], {}, :onchange => "$.post('#{issue_path(issue)}', {'_method':'put', 'issue[status]':this.value} );" %>
```

I found the answer in stevo's comments on this link:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

This updates the attribute but doesn't redirect the page. I can verify that the value is changing by going to the show view for the record. I hope this helps somebody else wrestling with this issue too.